# Pivot in ID in Python as change column name

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe like in Python

```
      ID                Peril

      1                  a

      1                  b

      1                  c

      2                  d

      2                  e

      2                  f

      2                  g

      2                  h

      2                  I
```

I want to manipulate the dataframe on ID by pivoting it and moving the Peril column as per sequence output like:

```
   ID          Peril1  Peril2  Peril3  Peril4  Peril5  Peril6

    1           a       b        c      NA       NA      NA

    2           d       e        f       g       I       j
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Suppose your data frame name is: `dframe`

> dframe.pivot('ID','Peril','value')

Comment: This doesn't work with the `value` column. Even with a column for `value` you'd need some code to get the column names `Peril1`, `Peril2`, ...